# How to write flat and read nested from ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to implement a functionality where ID of an account needs to be submitted while writing post and read additional info of an account with reading the post. How do I write the data with depth one but read data with more depth?

ModelSerializers:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'message', 'rating', 'create_date', 'close_date',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('id', 'username', 'full_name',)
```

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have updated the model serializers.

Answer (score 0):

As I get you want some of your fields to be read-only for example you need  'create_date' to be read but cannot be written

This is my approach:

models.py

```
# This extra modification done as late comments 
class Post(models.Model):
  ...
  def username(self):
     return self.author.username

  def full_name(self):
     return self.author.full_name
```

Serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # author = UserSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)  # Don't define this
    create_date_read_only = serializers.DateTimeField(required = False, read_only = True, source = 'create_date')
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        # username, full_name added to fileds tuple
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'username','full_name','message', 'rating', 'create_date_read_only', 'close_date',)
```

Do The same for other readonly fileds

Comment: I have later mentioned the read_only_fields array specifying create_date and other fields and it worked. I now need read only for full_name and username in UserSerializer used in PostSerializer and it's not working in nested serializer.

Comment: Have you declared author as ForeignKey to the User on Post model?

Comment: Yes..I have used author as foreign key to the user model

Comment: See the latest modification on my answer

Comment: I need user data to be returned nested inside my post data during read.

Comment: Just test it, that's the desired result

Answer (score 0):

you an use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for this.

You don't have to modify the model. Your serializer would look like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'my_field'...)

    def get_my_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.author.username
```

Comment: This misses the "write flat" part of the question, this only reads the flat version.